# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в файл

Tags: c#, winforms, кодировка

Записываю данные из буфера в текстовый файл(русский текст). Сначала пробовал так

```
public static void WriteFinalInfoInFile()
{
    string finalInfo = postTrack + "  " + location + "\n";
    File.AppendAllText("finalResult.txt", finalInfo); //write in file
}
```

потом так

```
public static void WriteFinalInfoInFile()
{
    string finalInfo = postTrack + "  " + location + "\n";
    File.AppendAllText("finalResult.txt", finalInfo, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)); //write in file
}
```

В обоих случаях, русские слова записываются как `????????????? ???????`. С латиницей проблем с записью нет.

Comment: Попробуйте открыть файл блокнота через notepad++ и проверить в какой кодировке там данные отображаются. Возможно следует задавать UTF-8. Так же попробуйте вставить русские символы вместо postTrack что-то вроде "строка". Возможно postTrack  имеет другую кодировку

Comment: @user2455111 изменил строку на string finalInfo = postTrack + "  " + "привет" + "\n"; все корректно записалось

Comment: значит вам нужно location переводить в нужную кодировку, попробуйте это сделать там, где получаете location. Возможно в пути присутствуют русские символы и кодировка при считывании задается другая. А как вы получаете location?

Comment: @user2455111 я пробовал изначально так делать(не задавать во входные параметры кодировку). в notepad++ ставил utf+8. все равно кракозябры. может имеет значение, что ос на сервере английская? Получаю location из буфера.

Comment: Ну может как то так попробовать Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(location)); Только разные кодировки попробовать.

Comment: или так 'Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(Message);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);'

Comment: Из названия метода: `AppendAllText` понятно, что он _добавляет_ текст в уже _существующий_ файл. Соответственно, добавлять нужно с той же кодировкой, с которой этот файл был создан. Отмечу, что по умолчанию используется кодировка, соответствующая локали ОС. Вывод: **всегда** указывайте кодировку при записи/чтении в/из файл(а). Если колеблетесь, какую выбрать - берите UTF-8.

Comment: Эээ, какой convert? C# не C++, в нём строки не зависят от кодировки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вы это имели ввиду ' File.AppendAllText("123.txt", finalInfo, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));' все равно некорректно пишет в файл. локализация ОС нерусская.